# To show all users of a particular place with location with instagram API php

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm doing a media search with instagram api with this API endpoint:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=XXXXXXX

But this gave me this result: `{"data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}` with empty data.

Someone can please tell me why I am getting empty data?

Thank you.

Comment: are u in sandbox mode ?

Comment: @krisrak Yes, my app is in sandbox mode.

Comment: in sandbox mode you will only see your and your sandbox user's photo in API response, when u go live, you will see all

Comment: Thank you @krisrak.

Yes, I am getting my and my sandbox users photos in API response.